# How to get movie or TV Season name from file name?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create movie database of my movies and TV Seasons stored on my NAS. But there is a problem the files are name like this:

- The.Walking.Dead.S04E01.HDTV.x264-ASAP
- R.I.P.D.2013.HDRip.x264.AC3-FooKas
- the.perks.of.being.a.wallflower.2012.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks

I tried to search those strings on many websites like TMDB.org but they can't find films like this. Is it possible to get a TMDB-friendly name of movie (or season) from those strings? I tried to replace dots by spaces but it didn't help. Any ideas?

I think that the following steps could work, but I'm not familiar with regular expressions:

- replace dots with spaces
- cut the string when the year appear
- search it in the TMDB.org API

I'm afraid there are files without the year or the year is after the quality (1080p,...) or after the uploader nickname.

Comment: If the format is always the same, for example movie title separated by dots, followed by the year, regex should work. Seems like you have a good plan... give it a shot and ask for help when you get stuck. A guy as adept as you at pirating movies and TV shows ought to be able to figure it out.

Comment: This is the problem - it seems to be always the same, but the movie R.I.P.D. is named with dots for example. And there is not always the same order of year, nick, quality etc. Any ideas about the regex? I'm not familiar with it at all :(    
BTW downloading movies without sharing it again is legal in the Czech Republic :)
edit: i gonna try to do something and I'll let you know.

Comment: I was just having fun with ya :) Right, the number of instances like that would be so small though you could most likely just manually repair those. There aren't that many movies with dotted names that I can think of. Regex is a big topic. Some research would benefit you greatly as I think you have some other issues, for instance movies with years in the name, etc. it may be smarter to clean up the name manually then automate the lookup process. Mainly because you can't currently control the format.

Comment: Just FYI: You are showing filenames of illegally ripped copyrighted material here, together with your real name. Seriously dude, how do you survive in real life ?

Comment: In the Czech Republic there is no law that prohibits download movies, music and many more. But we CAN'T share it :) So if i download the movie or some music just for me, it's OK in our country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These names are in free format, but all has the same elements, like 'name', 'year', 'codec', 'quality', 'resolution', etc... so you can create list of there elements and filtr them out.

The goal is to get maximum readable name of film

I never wrote something on php, so I first created script on Perl and then translate it to php as I can... so forgive me some hairy php code

```
$arr = array(
    'The.Walking.Dead.S04E01.HDTV.x264-ASAP',
    'R.I.P.D.2013.HDRip.x264.AC3-FooKas',
    'the.perks.of.being.a.wallflower.2012.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks'
);

foreach($arr as $value) {
        $words = preg_split('/[.]/', $value);
        $words = array_filter($words, create_function('$var','return !(preg_match("/(?:HDTV|bluray|\w{2,3}rip)|(?:x264)|(?:\d{4})|(?:\d{3,4}p)|(?:AC\d)/i", $var));'));
        echo join(' ', $words);
        echo "\n";
}
```

The output will be:

```
The Walking Dead S04E01
R I P D
the perks of being a wallflower
```

this is close enought... If something wrong with my code here is Perl's code, I sure it works:

```
my @data = (
    'The.Walking.Dead.S04E01.HDTV.x264-ASAP',
    'R.I.P.D.2013.HDRip.x264.AC3-FooKas',
    'the.perks.of.being.a.wallflower.2012.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks'
);
for my $el ( @data ) {
    my @words = grep 
        {!/(?:HDTV|bluray|\w{2,3}rip)|(?:x264)|(?:\d{4})|(?:\d{3,4}p)|(?:AC\d)/i}
        split /[.]/, $el;
    print join ' ', @words, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should at least get you started. I'm sure there are better ways to do this, and I'm sure you're going to find places where it needs to be tweaked to match all scenarios.

```
$subject = "the.perks.of.being.a.wallflower.2012.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks";
$pattern = '/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\.[0-9]{4}\./';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo substr(str_replace('.', ' ', $matches[0]), 0, -6);
```

Comment: Thank you as well for trying to help :)